# Replace high end laptop with server solution

Tags: server

Currently I have a quite high end laptop to run diverse software in the realm of (software) engineering and simulation/numerics.
I was wondering whether it would make sense to run something like a server at home or rent cloud space/computation capacity to run calculations faster and just display the results on a mobile device (notebook/tablet).
I am running windows 10 and what I would imagine is to see the screen exactly like I do now but to have the computations done on the server.
Do there exist suitable and practical solutions to that end? I just need some suggestions to start me in the right direction.
My requirements would be:

- minimum setup effort
- running applications "normally" saying I do not want to code my applications in a way to send out calculations to a server to calculate it, I want to run my OS on the server
- high computation power

  - possibility to extend if more is necessary
  - budget: up to 2000 Euro (2300 USD)

My current laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 260 with Intel Core i7. 
The idea is somehow to avoid the high cost of buying a mobile device with high performance when the same computation power is available cheaper as cloud/server solution and I have a great internet connection. Although the solution should ideally be able to run all my applications on the server and I just use a tablet or something as end device for display and IO.
Applications I am running often:

- MS Office solutions
- Chrome browser
- Matlab (numerical computations)
- C code
- Visual Studio
- Atom text editor

Comment: You didn't state what your current system was, is it a server class laptop with a Intel Xeon (server class) CPU?

Comment: Can you tell us what sort of things you're running? How fast they're running right now/how fast you'd like them to run? What your budget would be? Any size/power/noise requirements? If you're willing to buy used?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect a bit better my ideas. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: What do you think of Microsoft Azure? Is it suitable? I would be eligible for a 100$ trial as academia member. Can I install on azure vm all the applications I want or am I bound to their 'app store'?

Comment: I have closed this question as primarily opinion-based as only you can answer the question if you should build/buy a server or if you should use a cloud solution.

Comment: I am asking for directions for further research not an answer to the question: Should I buy it or not? Sorry that is not opinion based for me that is a discussion about trading off different dimensions of possible solutions.

Comment: The kind of solution you are asking for seems to be possible by using remote desktop combined with a high-end PC or VM accessible over the internet or on your LAN. Maybe you could update your question to ask for the pros/cons of using a cloud VM vs your own server PC for this type of workload.